TinyMCE Position of Cursor after Click/Mouseup
I need to be able to determine the position of the cursor after the TinyMCE control is clicked.  I also need to be able to react to this via a Click or MouseUp event.
Is that possible?
I've tried the getBookmark/moveToBookmark code to accomplish this but that requires a button press as far as I understand it.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
